# Regular expression or automata for language with odd number of 0's and odd number of 1's

Tags: automata, regular-languages, regular-expressions

Let $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ and $L=\{u \in \Sigma^* : u \text{ has odd number of 0's and odd number of 1's}\}$. How can I build a regular expression or an automaton for this language? I have no idea, and I guess $L$ is not regular, but I haven't been able to prove it with the pumping lemma.

If it is not regular, can you give me a hint to prove it?

Comment: Hint, it is regular.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hint: You are trying to solve two problems (i.e., odd number of zeros and odd number of ones) at once. Try to solve each separately instead and then combine the solutions appropriately.

Comment: So, solving each separately, doing the product of both automatas and taking as final states those which were final states in the single problem, isn't it? I mean, the union of both automatas

Comment: There is a mistake, is the product and intersection, not union

Comment: @vicase98 In the case of automata, yes, you want the intersection. (And the construction is fairly straightforward.) In the case of regexes, it is a bit more intricate, unfortunately.

Comment: Once I have the automata, I can get the regular expression. It's tedious, but algorithmic. Thank you for your help, I voted your response, but It doesn't appear until I have a specefic reputation